# Prefix some characters to the property name - JSON Serialization

Tags: c#, json.net

If I have a class like

```
class A
{
    public int Age {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Is there a way to serialize this object to generate properties with some arbitrary characters like this

```
[{ "prefix.age": 1, "prefix.name": "Apple" }]
```

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json for my serialization needs.

Comment: Is the prefix a fixed value or would it differ per property (or per class)?  Do you know the value of the prefix(es) at compile time, or is it determined at runtime?  Would it apply to all properties in a class or just some?  Would it apply to all classes or just some?

Comment: I am not sure why you would do this, seeing as your JSON class with properties would already serialize as {"class":{"property":"value","propertyB":"b"} it seems like unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just apply the [JsonProperty](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute to your class properties like this:

```
class A
{
    [JsonProperty("prefix.age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("prefix.name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then serialize it:

```
var a = new A { Age = 1, Name = "Apple" };
var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);
```

`serializedObject` will contain JSON string: `{"prefix.age":1,"prefix.name":"Apple"}`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your object is obj, you can serialize it as below manually:

```
string prefix = "prefix.";
A obj = new A();

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw);

Type objType = obj.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] objProperties = objType.GetProperties();

writer.WriteStartObject();

foreach (var property in objProperties)
{
    Object value = property.GetValue(obj, null);
    writer.WritePropertyName(prefix + property.Name.ToLower());
    writer.WriteValue(value);
}

writer.WriteEndObject();
```