# JSON serialize anonymous object with property name starting with special character

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to generate json from anonymous object but how can I generate @ sign with property name

this is what I need

```
[{
  "@type": "PropertyValue",
  "name": "test",
  "value": "some value"
},
{
 "@type": "PropertyValue",
  "name": "name",
  "value": "some value"
}]
```

this is what being generated

```
[{
  "type": "PropertyValue",
  "name": "test",
  "value": "some value"
},
{
 "type": "PropertyValue",
  "name": "name",
  "value": "some value"
}]
```

my code

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list.Select(x => JObject.FromObject(new { @type = "PropertyValue", name = "test", value = "some value"})).ToArray());
```

@ symbol is missing in the generated json string property name, how can I add @ symbol without doing a string replace?

asp.net 4.6.1

Comment: The `@` isn't part of the name, which is why it's being left out. The `@` prefix on identifiers is just there so you can use a reserved name as an identifier name. (You can also use it on non-reserved names, it's just not required.)

Comment: You will need a concrete type and the `JsonProperty` attribute to get that or use a dictionary `IDictionary<string, object>` for each object

Comment: Use a class with `JsonPropertyAttribute` to define custom property name, like `[JsonProperty("@type")] public string Type { get; set; }`

Comment: I don't want to create a class I want to use anonymous object.

Comment: Actually, this is NOT a duplicate of the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654741/prefix-some-characters-to-the-property-name-json-serialization because @Ali is specifically asking about doing it with anonymous type, and the question/answers referenced use regular classes with properties defined. Too bad it was marked as a duplicate...

Answer (score 3):

```
 [JsonProperty("@name")]
 public string Name { get; set; }
```

Tests:

```
public class Videogame
{
    [JsonProperty("@name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("release_date")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new Videogame();
        obj.Name = "MyName";
        obj.ReleaseDate = DateTime.Now;

        string str= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: I want to use an anonymous class.

Comment: You cannot achieve this using anonymous types. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217437/can-i-use-attributes-with-anonymous-classes