# How to serialize this C# return value into a JSON object?

Tags: c#

I have this object value that is being returned and I would like to convert it into a useful JSON object that I can inspect and manipulate. Ultimately, my goal is to validate the values of `username` and `accessKey`. But 2 things are throwing this off. Double `{{` makes it invalid JSON and `sauce:options` can't be converted into a property in a class.

```
{{
  "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge",
  "browserVersion": "latest",
  "platformName": "Windows 10",
  "sauce:options": {
    "username": "test",
    "accessKey": "123"
  }
}}
```

Here is what I tried:

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SauceSession.Options.ConfiguredEdgeOptions);
```

This `SauceSession.Options.ConfiguredEdgeOptions` returns that object I mentioned above.

Got this back:
**Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error getting value from 'BinaryLocation' on 'OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeOptions'.'**

I also tried this as per suggestions:

```
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SauceSession.Options.ConfiguredEdgeOptions);
```

And got back this **Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error getting value from 'BinaryLocation' on 'OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeOptions'.'**

Comment: This is...a JSON string? How are you "getting" this data? Are you looking to create a c# class to represent it?

Comment: Are you getting stuck on making a property which has a `:` in the name?

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: There are myriad ways to do this. Please narrow your question. Including what you've tried so far can help do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prefix some characters to the property name - JSON Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654741/prefix-some-characters-to-the-property-name-json-serialization)

Comment: If this is `json` it's not valid against RFC8259 or RFC7159.

Comment: @Nikolay, look into Newtonsoft. This makes it VERY easy to convert JSON into an object.

Comment: You can deserialise the `x:y` property using `JsonProperty` but the double `{{` and `}}` mean this isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @DavidG you're right that it's not valid JSON as jsonlint.com tells me. How do I handle this?

Comment: Fix the source of the JSON, or you will have to manually strip out these surrounding braces.

Comment: @DavidG I can't fix the source as it's a 3rd party API. So you think to do something like this: var optionsString = SauceSession.Options.ConfiguredEdgeOptions.ToString().Substring(1, SauceSession.Options.ConfiguredEdgeOptions.ToString().Length - 2); The only challenge here is that now it's a string with new line characters and all that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you cannot fix the source, you're going to have to apply a bodge to fix the JSON, for example this will work:

```
var fixedJson = sourceJson.Substring(1, Json.Length - 2);
```

Now you should have a couple of classes to hold your data, this way you can also cope with the unusual names:

```
public class Root
{
    public string BrowserName { get; set; }
    public string BrowserVersion { get; set; }
    public string PlatformName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sauce:options")]
    public Options SauceOptions { get; set; }
}

public class Options
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string AccessKey { get; set; }
}
```

And now you should be able to deserialise like this:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(fixedJson);
```

Comment: appreciate the solution. I got the following error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value "browserName" to type 'SimpleSauceTests.Root'. Path '', line 2, position 15.'

Comment: Then your source JSON doesn't have double braces. Just forget stripping them out.